# How to create form with image select image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need to create a form where one is textfield and another one is choose image. While selecting image that image name should be displayed and later when I submit the button the message and image need to be sent.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried image_picker ?

Comment: yes that is working fine, i need to store it and later with a message I need to send that into a server

Answer (score 1):

You can get the image name from `image_picker` through its path.

```
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;

final pickedFile = await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
String imageName = path.basename(pickedFile.path);
//Or
String imageName = pickedFile.path.split('/').last;
```